# I need a regEx to match string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have url like this

let url = "https://storage.cloud.google.com/dev-radius-backend/merchant/docs/1568875072010.jpg?organizationId=837717194226"

I need to match the substring "/merchant/docs/1568875072010.jpg"

I have found regEx to find the base of the url, but since in this case the filname is in between and not the end, I could not write a regEx myself.

But I found a way, which is not very efficient

```
var pathArray = url.split('/');
var a = pathArray[6].split('?')
var fileName = '/' + pathArray[4] + '/' + pathArray[5] + '/' + a[0]
```

I would need fileName to be "/merchant/docs/1568875072010.jpg"

Comment: often, the simplest way is the best solution. Regex sometimes consumes more memory and time to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The following Regex matches the pattern:
`\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+(?=\.)\.[^?]+`

Example:

```js
var url = 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/dev-radius-backend/merchant/docs/1568875072010.jpg?organizationId=837717194226';
var match = url.match(/\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+(?=\.)\.[^?]+/);
    
if (match) {
    console.log(match[0]); // "/merchant/docs/1568875072010.jpg"
    document.getElementById('result').innerText = match[0];
}
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
```

An explanation of the Regex:
`\/` - matches a literal `/`
`[^\/]+` - matches anything other than a `/` at least once
`(?=\.)` - a positive lookahead asserting that what immediately follows the current position in the string is a literal dot
`\.` - matches a literal dot
`[^?]+` matches anything that's not a literal question mark

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is confusing to me. Confusion is between:

**1:** if you want to match `/merchant/docs/1568875072010.jpg` to be in `url string` then use `includes` method

```
var url = "https://storage.cloud.google.com/dev-radius-backend/merchant/docs/1568875072010.jpg?organizationId=837717194226";
if (str.includes("/merchant/docs/1568875072010.jpg")) {
   alert('file found in URL')
}
```

**2:** If you want to extract that information from url string:

```
console.log(new URL(url).pathname.replace("/dev-radius-backend", ""));
```

Comment: I think the file name 1568875072010.jpg is dynamic and op wants to match all file names.. not sure

Comment: yeah !! really confusing. he said he wants to match... then he say, he needs .. hehehe

Comment: Im really sorry if my question is confusing. Yes, the filename is dynamic.